# How to copy the configuration when running a single test in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm

Let's say I'm writing my test cases, and I'm working on a specific one.

I can press ctrl+shift+r and PyCharm will run that specific test, all good, awesome and quick!

... Except my app won't start unless I set a couple of Environment Variables. Which I can do no problem in my default configuration, but when I run a test case with ctrl+shift+r it will create a new (empty) configuration, and it won't start.

Can i specify a default configuration to copy the temporary configuration from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create default configuration at `Edit Configurations` window:

1. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>
2. Select `Edit Configurations...`
3. In the left bar expand `Defaults` (icon with wrench and nut).
4. Find `Python tests`, select needed category (like `Unittests` or `Nosetests`).
5. In the configuration body find `Environment variables`, click "..." to add new as a future default value.
6. Apply or Ok to save your updates.
7. Now by default every new configuration which you will create through `Add new configuration` button (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> or green plus icon button in `Edit Configurations` window) must have your default env vars.

[docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/changing-run-debug-configuration-defaults.html)